# Newton's Law example

Tags: calculus

A cup of tea starts at 80 degres, and moved to outside at -10 degrees. After 7 minutes, tea cools to 55 degrees. How do I make a equation for it? I use Newton's law of cooling, Temperature = (Teperature of original - Temperature of environment)$e^{kt}$+Temperature of environment. So I made equation

$T(7)=(80-(-10))e^{-7k}-10$. Is check to be correct?

Comment: As far as I know newton's law writing the differential equation helps more

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi thats what I did

Comment: That much of the expression is correct, but you didn't use the information about the temperature _at_  $ \ t = 7 \ $ minutes. You would write $$  T(7) \ = \ (80-(-10))e^{-7k} \ + \ (-10) \ = \ 55 $$ and then solve this exponential equation for $ \ k \ $ in order to use this cooling function (for _that_ particular cup of tea) at other times. If the answer below is accurate and $ \ k \ = \ 0.046 \ $ , then your function is $$  T(t) \ = \ 90e^{-0.046·t} \ + \ (-10) \  . $$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi   In pre-calculus and first-semester calculus, when exponential functions are taught, examples of cooling functions are described as "Newton's Law of Cooling/Warming" without deriving them from the differential equation.

Comment: @boojum I am a math major so I don't know this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, I thought Newton's law of cooling was "the rate of heat loss of a body is directly proportional to the difference in the temperatures between the body and its surroundings" from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling).

Let the temperature of the cup be $y$. Let $t$ be time. The surrounding temperature is $-10$, thus the difference in temperatures is $(y+10)$. The rate of heat loss $-\frac{dy} {dt} = k(y+10)$, where $k$ is the constant of proportionality. Rearrange this to get $$\frac{dy}{y+10} = -k \space dt$$. We may integrate both sides to get $$ln(y+10) = -kt + C$$, or $$y = Ce^{-kt}-10$$. We know that $y= 80$ when $t=0$, so we have $$80 = C-10$$ or $$C=90$$. So our equation is now $$y=90e^{-kt}-10$$. We also know that $y=55$ when $t=7$. Thus, we get $$55=90e^{-7k}-10 \implies .72222222 =e^{-7k} \implies -.325 = -7k \implies k=.046$$. Thus, your equation should actually be $$y = 90e^{-.046t}-10$$. Now you can plug in $7$ to get your equation, but you know $k$ now.